# In jQuery is there such thing as a function name natively with out JS engagement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't found any examples that uses a function name in jQuery natively with out JS engagement. So yeah and I know jQuery is a library of JavaScript. I just like my functions to have names that's all.

**EXAMPLE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

For those of you who don't know what I mean is there any thing like this in jQuery aka named functions.

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function madeup_name(){
    $("button").click(function madeup_name(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried it out and it still works.

Comment: Define *"JS engagement"*.

Comment: What is "jQuery natively"?

Comment: What did the @Fox mean??

Comment: Anything related to JQuery will necessarily involve Javascript. JQuery is just a JS library.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: I know jQuery is a library of JavaScript so I know any thing jQuery can do JavaScript can also do it. I was just wondering because I keep running into jQuery function examples that all ways contains anonymous functions but not named functions. So yeah here's one of the many examples I notice online https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_this

Comment: In the example above, everything is 100% Jquery. Still no idea what you mean @Fox.

Comment: @Fox Are you actually asking about anonymous functions? You *can* used name functions with JQuery, if that's you're question. You often don't though as one of the main benefits of JQuery is its succinctness, which anonymous functions help.

Comment: Well you know how JS haves function name options for example function made_up_name () etc... does the jQuery library have this in its own library system structure since jQuery makes use of anonymous function all the time it's just a simple question of curiosity that's all.

Comment: @Fox What do you mean "does JQuery have its own library system structure"?

Comment: Using named functions instead of anonymous functions might make stack tracing better easier, other than that there's no point to naming them.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich **JavaScript** library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers.

In your question, you posted code which is (almost) **100% jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

`$(document).ready` is jQuery.

`$("button").click` is jQuery.

`$(this).hide()` is jQuery.

`madeup_name` - A Javascript you names created, which is called by the jQuery `ready` and `click` events.

These jQuery function **translate at the end to "pure" Javascript**. That's what jQuery is all about.

Since jQuery is Javascript, using JQuery does not conflict with using other "native" or "pure" Javascript functions or code. They mix together, as they were intended to.

Answer (score 0):

`madeup_name` is simply the name that *you* provide for the function passed to `.ready()` or `.click()`. That is not related to jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function madeup_name() {
    $("button").click(function madeup_name() {
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

An anonymous function can be passed to either `.ready()` or `.click()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

though you obviously could not reference an anonymous function within that context if you are trying to pass a function reference to `.ready()` or `.click()`

```
function () {
    $("button").click(function madeup_name(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready(/* how could we reference the anonymous function? */);

function madeup_name() {
    $("button").click(function madeup_name(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
}
// now we can reference the function named `madeup_name`
// though make sure that the reference is in the same scope
$(document).ready(madeup_name);
```

Comment: Sorry guys I'm just trying to understand jQuery better that's all because what would happen if I have a lot of functions in jQuery. Just saying so the power of distinguishment of other jQuery functions is not the key word function but its reference contains correct? For example like a id or a class id or a tag reference.

Comment: You can declare names for your functions and pass the function reference as the parameter `function fn(){//do stuff};$().ready(fn)` where a an anonymous function can also be passed `$().ready(function(){//do stuff})`. That functionality is not exclusive to jQuery. `function fn(el, index){console.log(el, index)};["a","b","c"].forEach(fn)`. jQuery has methods attached to the current jQuery object `$({})` or jQuery `$` or `jQuery` itself.